# Angular File-saver: How to prompt the 'Save As' window and not save directly

Tags: angular, typescript, window, save-as, filesaver.js

I am using the `file-saver` to save a file on client browser. However the file is directly getting downloaded.

```
const blob = new Blob([data.body], {type: 'application/'pdf});
  FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'export.pdf')
```

How to prompt the **"Save As" window** so user can save it with their own name and location.

I have seen a few answers on changing the settings in the browser, but wanted to know if `file-saver` has an api or any tweak in the code can prompt the window.

Note:- There aren't many resources on file-saver Save As API ( If not for browser settings.

Comment: I Am facing the same issue . Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
const mediaType = 'application/pdf';
const blob = new Blob([value], { type: mediaType });
const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(url);
```

Comment: So you're saying not to use the FileSaver to do it?

Comment: You can solve it without filesaver as well